# FB.ui request dialogs: preselecting some friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk

FB.ui Request dialogs: (With method: 'apprequests') allow you to send a request from your app.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

This says, you can specify one friend in the two value. However I want to specify N friends which are preselected, but can be edited. Is it possible in this widget. If not, What alternate widgets can I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible via that Facebook javascript sdk, most likely to be less spammy and not default to sending to every single person a user is friends with.  The way to get around this would be to build your own dialog using the graph api.  You would retrieve all the users that a person is friends with, present them with your own dialog to let them choose users, and then send graph api requests over for each request.

**Update:**
Per Facebook's [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/), you can only send invitations to users through their Requests dialog. And this dialog will not let you pre-populate all users as checked.  Graph api can only send to other users that have authenticated with the app.